# UICollectionView if will scroll recognize

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I need some help.
I have `UIcollectionView`, I am using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` Method. I need somehow to recognize if collection view will scroll to position or if item on needed `position` and will no scroll.
Another words, if scrolling will not start, scroll view delegate methods will not be called.

Thanks for help

Comment: could you show some code please

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to check wether your scroll view delegate methods will be called or not?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the indexPath you're interested in is in `[UICollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]`?

You can also use `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` to get the exact frame of the cell to determine if its partially shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CGRect cellFrame = [collectionView.visibleCells.lastObject frame];
CGRect collectionViewVisibleRect = collectionView.bounds;
collectionViewVisibleRect.origin.y = collectionView.contentOffset.y;
if (CGRectContainsRect(collectionViewVisibleRect, cellFrame))
   //no scroll
else
   //scroll
```

That does not takes into account contentInset that you might have.